# Rewrite Map Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We have a db which has from and to mappings of URL to redirect. Whenever someone wants a new redirect rule, instead of adding the rule in Apache we add them to the DB. A function does a lookup from the DB and does the redirect on each request.

We now want to replace that DB and instead use a new System which we have got in place. It is a content management system and hence we can host .txt files in it.

Ideally, i want to make a GET call to domain/rewrite.txt file in Apache and read the rules and if the request matches any of the rules then do a redirect.

I looked at the documentation [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#txt) and found the only way to do this is to use the external rewriting program for this. Still things aren't making sense. Can anyone help how to do this?

Comment: That CMS is exetrnal to the Apache where you want to do rewrites, or is running on the same server?

Comment: @Dusan I can push a file from the CMS to Apache.

Comment: But the document you linked describes exactly that scenario, reading rewrite map from txt file?